# Is there a way to put a newline in between a sorted collection or array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm using the sort method, and I was experimenting and it seems I can't find a solution. Can anyone give me a suggestion? the output always looks like an array. Can it have other format like a new line in between the string or integers, is there any way I can manipulate the output?

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set); 
Collections.sort(list); 

out.println("Number of Words: " + list.size());
out.println("Sorted Order: ");
out.println(list);
```

**My output**

```
Sorted Order:
[APPLE, BANANA, CHAIR, DOOR]
```

**Expected Output**

```
Sorted Order:
APPLE
BANANA
CHAIR
DOOR
```

Comment: imagine that there is already an input. like the 4 words below

Comment: `list.forEach(i -> System.out.format("- %s\n", i));`

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

`out.println(list);`

with

`list.forEach(System.out::println)`

That should do it.

Comment: it does not work it says incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression missing return value

Comment: What is this? A lambda or a method reference?. Looks like a lambda that returns a method reference.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Fixed, typed it dry, didn't pay attention.

Comment: @JanDierekhArroyo Try again, I made a typo.